# MYSQL Select Records Greater Than OR First

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Very simple,

I have a table like:

```
ID,
Name,
Key,
Score
```

I want to select all the keys from the table that has the score greater or equal than 0.5 or just the highest(if there aren't).

Data example:

```
1, Messi, AAA, 0.8
2, Messi, AAA, 0.7
3, Ronaldo, BBB, 0.1
4, Ronaldo, BBB, 0.3
5, Ronaldo, BBB, 0.4
6, Rooney, CCC, 0.9
7, Rooney, CCC, 0.4
8, Rooney, CCC, 0.2
```

I expect the result to be:

```
1, AAA, 0.8
2, AAA, 0.7
3, BBB, 0.4
6, CCC, 0.9
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    tbl.*
FROM
    table1 AS tbl
WHERE
    tbl.Score>0.5
    OR 
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(t.Score)
        FROM
            table1 AS t
        WHERE 
            t.Name=tbl.Name
            AND t.[Key]=tbl.[Key]
    ) = tbl.Score
```

This will get you this result:

```
1   Messi   AAA 0.8
2   Messi   AAA 0.7
5   Ronaldo BBB 0.4
6   Rooney  CCC 0.9
```

Comment: Simple and clean.
Life saver!